# Step into virtual functions in gdb with clion

Tags: c++, x86, gdb, overriding, clion

when stepping into a virtual function, gdb will not stop at breakpoints set inside the virtual function, and Clion will display the assembly code of the function instead of the source C++ file.

I understand that a virtual function call means calling a function pointer from the vtable, but Clion is clearly aware of how the assembly corresponds to the C++ code.

Anything would be helpful, because I am struggling to get the code to break inside the virtual function, and it's very hard to debug it like that.

A screenshot of the disassembly view:
[image]

Comment: I'd wonder if gdb wouldn't be able to source code debug virtual functions. Some things, I would check first: 1. all code compiled with `-g` (debug) 2. Has source code been changed/moved after compiling? 3. debug symbols visible (I just learnt that gcc can build debug symbols into separate files as I know it from MSVC++.) 4. Not sure how this applies to gcc - I know this issue from MS VS (which actually has excellent debugger): Even with pdb files in place (the ext. debug db files of VC++) source code debugging may fail for prebuilt libs. because source code paths simply doesn't match anymore.